# Function clause error Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I am trying to understand process communication in erlang. Here I have a master process and five friends process. If a friend sends a message to any of the other 5 they have to reply back. But the master should be aware of all this. I am pasting the code below.

```
-module(prog).
-import(lists,[append/2,concat/1]).

-import(maps,[from_lists/1,find/2,get/2,update/3]).
-import(string,[equal/2]).
-import(file,[consult/1]).
-export([create_process/1,friends/4, master/1, main/0,prnt/1]).     



%% CREATE PROCESS 
create_process([])->ok;
create_process([H|T])->
    {A,B} = H,
    Pid = spawn(prog,friends,[B,self(),0,A]),
    register(A,Pid),
    create_process(T).


%% FRIENDS PROCESS
friends(Msg, M_pid, State, Self_name)->
    S = lists:concat([Self_name," state =",State,"\n"]),
    io:fwrite(S),
    if
        State == 0 ->
            timer:sleep(500),
            io:fwrite("~p~n",[Self_name]),
            lists:foreach(fun(X) -> whereis(X)!{Self_name,"intro",self()} end, Msg),
            friends(Msg, M_pid, State + 1, Self_name);
        State > 0 ->
            receive
                {Process_name, Process_msg, Process_id} -> 
                    I = equal(Process_msg,"intro"),
                    R = equal(Process_msg,"reply"),
                    XxX = lists:concat([Self_name," recieved ",Process_msg," from ",Process_name,"\n"]),
                    io:fwrite(XxX),
                    if
                        I == true ->
                            io:fwrite("~p~n",[whereis(Process_name)]),
                            M_pid!{lists:concat([Self_name," received intro message from ", Process_name , "[",Process_id,"]"]), self()},
                            io:fwrite(I),
                            whereis(Process_name)!{Self_name, "reply",self()},

                            friends(Msg, M_pid, State + 1, Self_name);
                        R == true ->
                            M_pid!{lists:concat([Self_name," received reply message from ", Process_name , "[",Process_id,"]"]), self()},
                            io:fwrite(R),
                            friends(Msg, M_pid, State + 1, Self_name)
                    end
            after
                1000->
                    io:fwrite(lists:concat([Self_name," has received no calls for 1 second, ending..."]))
            end

    end.


master(State)->
    receive
        {Process_message, Process_id} ->
            io:fwrite(Process_message),
            master(State+1)
    after
        2000->
            ok
    end.


main() ->
    B = [{john, [jill,joe,bob]},
{jill, [bob,joe,bob]},
{sue, [jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]},
{bob, [john]},
{joe, [sue]}],
    create_process(B),
    io:fwrite("~p~n",[whereis(sue)]),

    master(0).
```

I think the line in **friends()** function,

```
M_pid!{lists:concat([Self_name," received intro message from ", Process_name , "[",Process_id,"]"]), self()}
```

is the cause of error but I cannot understand why. M_pid is known and I am concatenating all the info and sending it to master but I am confused why it isnt working.

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Error in process <0.55.0> with exit value: {function_clause,[{lists,thing_to_list,
                         [<0.54.0>],
                         [{file,"lists.erl"},{line,603}]},
                  {lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1250}]},
                  {lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1250}]},
                  {prog,friends,4,[{file,"prog.erl"},{line,45}]}]}
```

I dont know what is causing the error. Sorry for asking noob questions and thanks for your help.

Comment: Try changing `Process_id` to `pid_to_list(Process_id)` in both the calls to `lists:concat/2`.

Comment: Hi, Dogbert. I will go home and give it a try. But out of curiosity what is the difference? and why was Process_id messing up list:concat/2 ?

Comment: The error message you are reporting doesn't look consistent with the piece of code (no lists:flatmap/2 call at line 45 or anywhere else). I have 2 remarks: 1/ you have no recursive call in the after clauses, so if a process hits this clause, it will stop. 2/ it is very unusual to use the import directive, generally, erlang programmers prefer to show explicitly the fully qualified calls (as you do) and in this case the import directive is useless.

Answer (score 3):

An example of what Dogbert discovered:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

go() ->
    Pid = spawn(my, nothing, []),
    lists:concat(["hello", Pid]).


nothing() -> nothing.
```

In the shell:

```
2> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

3> my:go().
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    lists:thing_to_list(<0.75.0>) (lists.erl, line 603)
     in function  lists:flatmap/2 (lists.erl, line 1250)
     in call from lists:flatmap/2 (lists.erl, line 1250)
4>
```

But:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

go() ->
    Pid = spawn(my, nothing, []),
    lists:concat(["hello", pid_to_list(Pid)]).

nothing() -> nothing.
```

In the shell:

```
4> c(my).  
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

5> my:go().
"hello<0.83.0>"
```

From the [erl docs](https://erldocs.com/19.0/stdlib/lists.html?i=0&search=lists:concat#concat/1):

```
concat(Things) -> string()
    Things = [Thing]
    Thing = atom() | integer() | float() | string()
```

The list that you feed concat() must contain either atoms, integers, floats, or strings.  A pid is neither an atom, integer, float, nor string, so a pid cannot be used with concat().  However, [pid_to_list()](https://erldocs.com/19.0/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=pid_to#pid_to_list/1) returns a string:

```
pid_to_list(Pid) -> string()
    Pid = pid()
```

As you can see, a pid has its own type: pid().

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code.
Where you went wrong was to pass `Process_id`(which is of type `pid()`) to `lists:concat/1`.

Let us try to understand this error:

```
{function_clause,[{lists,thing_to_list,
                         [<0.84.0>],
                         [{file,"lists.erl"},{line,603}]},
                  {lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1250}]},
                  {lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1250}]},
                  {prog,friends,4,[{file,"prog.erl"},{line,39}]}]}
```

It states the function `lists:thing_to_list/1` has no definition(see the word `function_clause` in the error log) which accepts an argument of type `pid()` as denoted here by `[<0.84.0>]`.

Strings are represented as lists in erlang, which is why we use lists:concat/1.

As @7stud pointed out these are the valid types which can be passed to `lists:concat/1` as per the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#concat-1):

```
atom() | integer() | float() | string()
```

There are 2 occurrences of the following line. Fix them and you are good to go:

**Incorrect Code:**

```
M_pid!{lists:concat([Self_name," received intro message from ", Process_name , "[",Process_id,"]"]), self()},
```

**Corrected Code**

```
M_pid!{lists:concat([Self_name," received intro message from ", Process_name , "[",pid_to_list(Process_id),"]"]), self()},
```

Notice the use of the function `erlang:pid_to_list/1`. As per the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#pid_to_list-1) the function accepts type `pid()` and returns it as `string()`.